# Telerik Report viewer not working when combined with Asp.net core in Asp .net Boilerplate

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, telerik, aspnetboilerplate

I had this client project where I am supposed to list data from customer table in a Telerik report viewer.
The **Asp.net boilerplate** solution I use is of

> Asp.net core 2.0 with Multipage web application (.net core 2.2 ,  .net framework 4.6.1)

I am attaching the error as below :
[image]

I have tried all solution. The strange thing here is if I set a separate project for api and then run both the projects i.e. 
1) ABP solution
2) Rest API project

Then it works fine. But the same thing doesn't work when I have api in ABP solution. The following image shows the data in **Telerik report viewer**. This is when I run 2 projects together, it works great. 
Also this Telerik report works fine If I choose Asp.net MVC instead of .Net core.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: @aaron 
This is the only console error we get
"Uncaught (in promise) Invalid ClientId" 
We don't get any stack trace in VS.
I can upload the solution to GitHub if you would like to check.

Comment: There should be a stack trace in browser console.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: Just for the records, I found that the report service should respond "AS IS", without any other wrappers.  In my case, the clientID was wrapped around other properties my dev framework puts.  Hope this helps.